# Once offline_access is removed, will asking for it cause an error?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

According to the developer roadmap, offline_access is schedule for removal on Oct 3: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

I am currently asking for offline_access for my iOS application. Because this application is a native iOS app deployed through the app store, I can't control it's behavior retroactively unless a user updates (unlike a web app which can be modified at any time). I can release an update to the app of course which does not ask for the permission, *but will users who still have older versions that do ask for the permission see an error, or will the authentication dialog ignore the offline_access scope?*

Note: if I put a random junk permission like "foobar" into the scope list, the dialog definitely does present an error. Hence my concern - will asking for offline_access break the application after Oct 3?

AFAICS there is no clear answer to this question on the deprecation documentation page: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can test that by putting the migration on from your app settings.
And with my testing it shows that there isn't any error shown even if you have the parameter in the scope. So don't worry, be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

the future is unknown.
what is known, and may be new to you is that apps are now automatically granted offline access for 60 days which recharges each time

Comment: If by "automatically granted offline access for 60 days" you mean that tokens by default will typically live for 60 days, I'm aware of that. The term "offline access" referes to a specific thing: an individual permission you can put in the scope list given to the auth dialog. My question is whether including this permission in the scope list will cause an error after Oct 3. This is an important question for native application developers whose users are not guaranteed to upgrade. Moreover the answer certainly is "known" at least to Facebook internally, it's just not clearly documented.